# Email thrown to spam - what's wrong?

Tags: email

I tried many ways, to solve the problem, that mails are throw to spam in gmail... I set the Received: from, before it shown in gmail the note "noreply@odsantu.sk via lvps83-169-17-110.dedicated.hosteurope.de"... Now I have no idea, what can be wrong...

```
Delivered-To: dobikos@gmail.com
Received: by 10.14.125.5 with SMTP id y5csp282730eeh;
        Thu, 22 Nov 2012 16:08:08 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.14.0.198 with SMTP id 46mr6776443eeb.21.1353629288333;
        Thu, 22 Nov 2012 16:08:08 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <anonymous@vipfp.eu>
Received: from vipfp.eu (lvps83-169-17-110.dedicated.hosteurope.de. [83.169.17.110])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id a9si9044494eeo.114.2012.11.22.16.08.08
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Thu, 22 Nov 2012 16:08:08 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 83.169.17.110 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of anonymous@vipfp.eu) client-ip=83.169.17.110;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 83.169.17.110 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of anonymous@vipfp.eu) smtp.mail=anonymous@vipfp.eu
Received: (qmail 13333 invoked by uid 33); 23 Nov 2012 01:08:07 +0100
To: dobikos@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UG90dnJkZW5pZSBvYmplZG7DoXZreSBsaXN0dSBvZCBTYW4=?=  =?UTF-8?B?dHU=?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:SendmailMailer.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: Nette Framework
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 01:08:07 +0100
From: "OdSantu.sk" <noreply@odsantu.sk>
Message-ID: <hyzaah4290@odsantu.sk>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="--------6p2unvd5n4"

----------6p2unvd5n4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

.
.
.
contents
.
.
.

----------6p2unvd5n4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

.
.
.
contents
.
.
.

----------6p2unvd5n4--
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't change how gmail interprets an email as spam.

Comment: Apart from changing the content, you should really configure [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records for `vipfp.eu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying out of spam filters is a bit like search engine optimization: it's a moving target.

But some basics:

- send from a known hostname not some random IP
- include user details (eg username, firstname, etc) in the content
- make sure the From and Reply-to match
- include actual text (empty or image emails often show as spam)
- don't include links that look like spoofs

There are sites out there that track the latest trends you should be able to find them on Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
Received: from vipfp.eu (lvps83-169-17-110.dedicated.hosteurope.de.
```

your system has a generic rDNS pointer which does not match the HELO, this can trigger spam filters. set your PTR to `vipfp.eu` as well in your vps control panel (or tell your vps hoster to do it for you if there is no reverse dns option in the control panel)

```
Received-SPF: neutral
```

consider adding SPF

Comment: thank you, I've already did these, but the problem was Return-Path... it detected anonymous@vipfp.eu as spam, admin@odsantu.sk is OK... thanks again